# Do I need to worry about water damage along walls?

Tags: water, walls, plaster, water-damage

We had a contractor come over and do some demolition in our bathroom because we're going to convert our tub into a stand-up shower. When using the saw to cut through some material, his apprentice accidentally nicked the cold-water hose and doused everything in water for a good 3-4 minutes before I got a chance to shut off the water main (I know... I should've done it from the very beginning).

Here's the culprit hose on the 2nd floor:

[image]

And here's our ceiling directly below, on the 1st floor. Tons of dripping water, and it ended ripping off the painted finish:

[image]

The contractor was very apologetic, and is going to take off that entire section of ceiling and replace it entirely. The space between the walls dripped water all the way down to the basement, but don't show immediate surface damage. The walls are plaster, and most definitely contain lead paint because this house is old. My question is, do I need to do anything to prevent permanent water damage along the walls? If so, what should I be on the lookout for?

House is in the Pacific Northwest, and we keep our heater at 70-degrees... would that be enough to evaporate any residual water?

Answer (score 2):

Contact you insurance to find out if they will contribute.

Possibly Not all water came out. Inspect by drilling small holes about a inch above the floor to see if any water comes out.

Check what power outlets you have and are they sufficient to drive equipment like fans, dehumidifier and heaters.

You can rent those for example at Home Depo.

[home depo](https://www.homedepot.com/c/drying_and_restoration_equipment_rental)

Comment: Shouldn't the contractor have insurance that will pay for it all?